# Error in getting correct output from Sankey Plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am new to plotly in python. I am trying to create the Sankey plot. The idea is to show the change ofsize of each Topic month on month. This is my pandas sample DataFrame. There are more Topic
and also each Topic has more month and year. That makes the dataframe tall.

```
 df
    year    month   Topic         Size  
  1 2022    1        1.0            40  
  2 2022    1        2.0            36  
  3 2022    1        3.0            70  
  4 2022    1        4.0            42  
  5 2022    1        5.0            25  
  6 2022    1        6.0            48  
  7 2022    2        1.0            14  
  8 2022    2        2.0            34
  9 2022    2        3.0            39  
 10 2022    2        4.0            210 
 11 2022    2        5.0            106 
 12 2022    2        6.0            70  
 13 2022    3        1.0            47  
 14 2022    3        2.0            45  
 15 2022    3        3.0            78  
 16 2022    3        4.0            114 
 17 2022    3        5.0            84
 18 2022    3        6.0            78
 19 2022    4        1.0            42  
 20 2022    4        2.0            45  
 21 2022    4        3.0            78  
 22 2022    4        4.0            28  
 23 2022    4        5.0            74
 24 2022    4        6.0            44
 25 2022    5        1.0            57  
 26 2022    5        2.0            45  
 27 2022    5        3.0            82  
 28 2022    5        4.0            94  
 29 2022    5        5.0            54
 30 2022    5        6.0            24
```

I have prepared the following from plotly demo. Ideally, source_node should be month1 and month2, month3, month4 should be intermittent nodes. month5 is the target node. All the topics will flow across the months. I am missing how to create  variables node_label, source_node, target_node so that the following code works. I am not getting the correct plot output

```
 node_label = ?
 source_node = ?
 target_node = ?
 values = df['Size']

from webcolors import hex_to_rgb
%matplotlib inline

from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objects as go # Import the graphical object

fig = go.Figure( 
data=[go.Sankey( # The plot we are interest
    # This part is for the node information
    node = dict( 
        label = node_label
    ),
    # This part is for the link information
    link = dict(
        source = source_node,
        target = target_node,
        value = values
    ))])

 # With this save the plots 
 plot(fig,
 image_filename='sankey_plot_1', 
 image='png', 
 image_width=5000, 
 image_height=3000)

 # And shows the plot
 fig.show()
```

Comment: @Rob Raymond can you please help

Comment: Hello @shan! I would like to give you a tip. Try to use df.to_dict(orient="records"), it will make easier the life of the community members that will try to help you.